# linux - how to start listening to stdin and redirecting the lines?

Tags: linux, bash

I've written a simple script that runs through a given list of hosts and executed a given command on these hosts.
the script basiclly looks like:

```
while read host; do
    ssh -f $user@$host $@
echo < servers
```

I want to be able to run the script so that it will start "listening" to lines from stdin and running them in the loop instead of $@.
The script will stop working by a normal termination - ctrl +c..

Any idea?

Comment: Does this have to be in bash?

Comment: That `do` is missing a `done`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm reading the question properly, you want to send a set of commands to a bunch of servers, all of which are passed along singularly.

For this, you should wrap the inner loop in an outer read loop; something akin to:

```
while read command; do
    while read host; do
        ssh -f $user@$host "$command"
        echo 
    done < servers
done
```

When run, you can type a command and it is executed across all the servers. Resolving issues with shell escape characters being sent to the remote system is an exercise for the developer.

Answer (score 0):

Your script is already doing that! Just understand how it works - just save it into some.bash file:

```
user="myuser"
while read host; do
    ssh -f $user@$host $@
done
```

$@ means add remaining parameters from command line, if you use none, it will add none

**read host** will read the line - not just word.

So basically, when you run it:

```
www.somehost.com
--> ssh -f myuser@www.somehost.com
www.somehost.com other parameters
--> ssh -f myuser@www.somehost.com other parameters
```

Comment: This is taking the arguments for ssh from the script's command line, not standard input.